# Não selecionar nenhum valor da dropdownlist

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Olá
Tenho a seguinte dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => @item4.Status, new List<SelectListItem>
                                     {                                      
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Sem malha", Value = "Sem malha"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "No gabinete (dos moldes)", Value = "No gabinete (dos moldes)"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "A testar corte", Value = "A testar corte"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "A bordar", Value = "A bordar"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para cortar", Value = "Para cortar"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Em corte", Value = "Em corte"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "A estampar", Value = "A estampar"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para colocar", Value = "Para colocar"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Em confeção", Value = "Em confeção"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para aparar", Value = "Para aparar"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para lavar", Value = "Para lavar"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para tingir", Value = "Para tingir"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para ferros", Value = "Para ferros"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para arranjos", Value = "Para arranjos"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para embalagem", Value = "Para embalagem"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Embalado", Value = "Embalado"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Para controle", Value = "Para controle"},
                                       }, @item4.Status, new { @class = "Status form-control form-control-sm font-weight-bold", disabled = true })
```

só que quando valor é null na minha tabela ele assume sempre o primeiro valor.
Como posso resolver isso?

Os valores estão a ser enviados por um jquery.

[image: img]

Obrigado,

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um item no primeiro índice do dropdownlist apenas como placeholder e colocar o atributo disabled = disabled nele.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas adicione o primeiro item da lista com o value vazio.

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Selecione...", Value = ""},
```